# Portable application: s3 and Google cloud storage

Tags: python, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, portability

I want to write an application which is portable.

With "portable" I mean that it can be used to access these storages:

- amazon s3
- google cloud storage
- Eucalyptus Storage

The software should be developed using Python.

I am unsure how to start, since I could not find a library which supports all three storages.

Comment: I don't know if this could help but take a look at Storage Transfer Service from google cloud. Also,take a look at https://pypi.org/project/cloudstorage/ . I don't know if it supports Eucalyptus Storage

Comment: Since Eucalyptus aims to provide AWS compatible APIs, don't you just need any Google and AWS compatible package - e.g. cloudstorage or django-storages?

Comment: @PeterBrittain if you write your comment as answer, then I will upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to connect to Google Cloud Storage from your application, you can follow the steps described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage) to learn how to read from a storage bucket or write into one using the application. It also includes an example on how to perform those steps.

Please be aware that this would only work for Google Cloud Storage. As for Amazon and Eucalyptus, I would not be able to provide the help you need.

**UPDATE**

After confirming that the answer I posted above is not what you wish for your application, we can start from @GautamKumar's answer and continue from there, so let's check the `boto` library. As Gautam said, [`boto3`](https://github.com/boto/boto3) is useful to connect to Amazon S3 buckets,   so let's see if there are also options for Eucalyptus and Google Cloud Storage.

I could check that the same library can be used to connect to [Eucalyptus](https://github.com/eucalyptus/eucalyptus/wiki/Boto), including options for both EC2 and S3. You can find some examples on how to use `boto3` with Eucalyptus [in this link](https://blogs.mindspew-age.com/tag/boto3/).

Also, there is a [plugin](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-plugin) available for accessing Google Cloud Storage and performing operations with their buckets by using the XML API. You would also need `gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin` in order to authenticate into Cloud Storage. In the provided link you can check how to perform the different operations to access the Cloud Storage buckets and perform different operations with them.

Comment: This question is about a portable way to solve this. Accessing only Google Cloud Storage does not fit to the question.

Comment: Apologies if my answer did not suit what you were looking for. I have updated it with new information that could be more suitable for your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use boto3 for accessing any services of Amazon.

Comment: you say "any services of Amazon". Does this include google and Eucalyptus storage?

Comment: Yes, you can use google and Eucalyptus storage using boto3.  documentation for using cloud storage via boto3 is https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-gsutil   and for Eucalyptus you can go through https://github.com/eucalyptus/eucalyptus/wiki/Boto.

Answer (score 1):

Since Eucalyptus aims to provide [AWS compatible APIs](https://github.com/eucalyptus/eucalyptus/wiki/AWS-Tools), all you need is a package that is Google and AWS compatible.

A quick search online finds at least a couple of possible answers:

- https://pypi.org/project/cloudstorage/
- https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/